# How to rename shaders and shading engine for specific transform body parts if it's assign to whole body

Tags: python, maya

So here my objective is to rename shaders and shading engines name depending upon the mesh
for example :

shader <body_MAT> and shading engine <body_MATSG> is assigned to whole body but i want to rename this shader for  ["LT_Hand_Geo", "RT_Hand_Geo", "LT_Arm_Geo", "RT_Arm_Geo", "LT_Leg_Geo", "RT_Leg_Geo"] with name like

Hand_MAT and Hand_MATSG for both Hand transforms
Arm_MAT and Arm_MATSG for both Arm transforms
Leg_MAT and Leg_MATSG for both Leg transforms

And let it be body_MAT and body_MATSG for remaining transforms like, Head, Hair, Pelvis etc.

Here this the code I have tried till now

```
    class CommonShaders(qc_base_class.QC):
"""
validate joints in _Jnt_Grp having _Jnt as suffix.
Fix : add _GEO as suffix for all meshes
"""

def __init__(self):
    # qc_base_class.QC.__init__(self)
    super(CommonShaders, self).__init__()
    self.fix_button = True
    self.prj_mat = {"default_show": [], "lotb": ["Hand_MAT", "Leg_MAT", "Arm_MAT"]}

@staticmethod
def description():
    return """<p><b>Common Shader:</p></b>
    <p> This is to check if hands,arms and legs component has same shaders assigned to them respoectively or not </p>
    <p><b>Auto-Fix:</b> This will assign same shaders to hands, arms and legs components with suitable naming convention</p>
    """

def validation(self):
    """
    return components if they don't have similar shaders assigned to them

    """
    self.transforms = cmds.ls(transforms=True)
    self.shading_engines = {}
    self.valid_failed_list = []
    self.selected_mesh = ["LT_Hand_Geo", "RT_Hand_Geo", "LT_Arm_Geo", "RT_Arm_Geo", "LT_Leg_Geo", "RT_Leg_Geo"]
    self.prj_mat = {"default_show": [], "lotb": list(set([i.split('_')[1] + '_MAT' for i in self.selected_mesh]))}

    for transform in self.transforms:
        if transform in self.selected_mesh:
            shapes = cmds.listRelatives(transform, shapes=True)
            if shapes:
                shading_engine = cmds.listConnections(shapes[0], type="shadingEngine")
                if shading_engine:
                    shading_engine_name = shading_engine[0]
                    shader_name = \
                        cmds.connectionInfo("%s.surfaceShader" % shading_engine_name, sfd=1).split(".")[0]
                    self.shading_engines[transform] = [shading_engine[0], shader_name]

    for transform in self.selected_mesh:
        paired_transform = transform.replace("LT_", "RT_") if "LT_" in transform else transform.replace(
            "RT_", "LT_")
        if paired_transform in self.shading_engines.keys():
            if self.shading_engines[transform][0] != self.shading_engines[paired_transform][0] or \
                    self.shading_engines[transform][1] != self.shading_engines[paired_transform][1] or \
                    self.shading_engines[transform][0] != (transform.split('_')[1] + '_MATSG') or \
                    self.shading_engines[transform][1] != (transform.split('_')[1] + '_MAT'):
                self.valid_failed_list.append(transform)

    return False if self.valid_failed_list else True

def assign_shading_engine(self, transform, shader_name, shading_engine_name):
    shapes = cmds.listRelatives(transform, shapes=True)
    if shapes:
        cmds.sets(shapes[0], e=True, forceElement=shading_engine_name)
        cmds.connectAttr("%s.outColor" % shader_name, "%s.surfaceShader" % shading_engine_name, f=True)

def fix(self):
    """
    This function will not   rename duplicated named meshes
    :return:
    """

    for transform in self.valid_failed_list:
        paired_transform = transform.replace("LT_", "RT_") if "LT_" in transform else transform.replace(
            "RT_", "LT_")
        self.shader_name = transform.split('_')[1] + '_MAT'
        self.shading_engine_name = self.shader_name + 'SG'

        if self.shading_engines[transform][0] == self.shading_engines[paired_transform][0] and self.shading_engines[transform][1] == self.shading_engines[paired_transform][1]:
            shading_engine = self.shading_engines[transform][0]
            if shading_engine != self.shading_engine_name:
                cmds.rename(shading_engine, self.shading_engine_name)
                self.shading_engines[transform][0] = self.shading_engine_name
            shader = self.shading_engines[transform][1]
            if shader != self.shader_name:
                cmds.rename(shader, self.shader_name)
                self.shading_engines[transform][1] = self.shader_name

            self.assign_shading_engine(transform, self.shader_name, self.shading_engine_name)
            self.assign_shading_engine(paired_transform, self.shader_name, self.shading_engine_name)

        elif self.shading_engines[transform][0] != self.shading_engines[paired_transform][0] or self.shading_engines[transform][1] != self.shading_engines[paired_transform][1]:
            shading_engine = self.shading_engines[transform][0]
            shader = self.shading_engines[transform][1]
            if shading_engine != self.shading_engine_name:
                cmds.rename(shading_engine, self.shading_engine_name)
                self.shading_engines[transform][0] = self.shading_engine_name
            if shader != self.shader_name:
                cmds.rename(shader, self.shader_name)
                self.shading_engines[transform][1] = self.shader_name

            self.assign_shading_engine(transform, self.shader_name, self.shading_engine_name)
            self.assign_shading_engine(paired_transform, self.shader_name, self.shading_engine_name)

        elif self.shading_engines[transform][0] == (transform.split('_')[1] + '_MATSG') and self.shading_engines[transform][1] == (transform.split('_')[1] + '_MAT'):
            self.assign_shading_engine(transform, self.shader_name, self.shading_engine_name)
            self.assign_shading_engine(paired_transform, self.shader_name, self.shading_engine_name)

    mel.eval('hyperShadePanelMenuCommand("hyperShadePanel1", "deleteUnusedNodes");')
```

So basically here I am renaming and assigning for the body part pairs accordingly.

And error I am getting is `" No objects found "` on this line `cmds.rename(shading_engine, self.shading_engine_name)`.

And also in case of whole body assigned a single shader it'll change the name of shader as a whole where I only want to change the shader name for selected meshes not every one of them even though it's a single shader and shading engine.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Some open questions: Do you have separate meshes named correctly for body, hands, arm... or is it one solid mesh and you only have per face shading? And you already have separate shaders? Or do you only have one shader and you want to duplicate it, rename it and assign it for every pair of body parts?

Comment: @haggikrey 


1) Yes I have separate meshes named correctly as follows :
["LT_Hand_Geo", "RT_Hand_Geo", "LT_Arm_Geo", "RT_Arm_Geo", "LT_Leg_Geo", "RT_Leg_Geo"]


2) For shaders here can be few conditions :


a) A one single shader that's assigned to whole body and I'll need to duplicate it and assign it to body parts and then rename it.


b) Separate shaders for pairs in this case I need to assign any one of the shader to the other pair and then rename it.


I am renaming shaders and shading engine as I need final name for body part pair to be body_part_MAT and body_part_MATSG

Comment: And you did not write anything about an error. I suppose your code does not work? And please always post not a part but a simple excutable script.

Comment: @haggikrey I have added the whole code and the issues I am facing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here. Every time you rename something you can **never** be sure that the resulting name is really the one you want. So you should use the result of the rename command as the new name. Next in your loop you iterate over your dictionary and try to rename shaders and shading engines even if they are already renamed. Even if you try to update your dictionary it seems to fail.

I recommend try to simplify your code a bit. e.g. you could simply get the current shader from any `RT_` geo duplicate it to be sure that it is unique, rename it and assign it to the geo and it's counterpart. No need for all these checkings if I understand the procedure correctly.

Comment: Rather than this what if i maintain a dictionary like this 

('LT_Hand_Geo', [u'LT_Hand_1007_MAT', 'Hand_MAT'])
('RT_Hand_Geo', [u'sdsasd', 'Hand_MAT'])
('LT_Arm_Geo', [u'LT_Arm_1005_MAT', 'Arm_MAT'])
('RT_Arm_Geo', [u'RT_Arm_1006_MAT', 'Arm_MAT'])
('LT_Leg_Geo', [u'LT_Leg_46_MAT', 'Leg_MAT'])
('RT_Leg_Geo', [u'RT_Leg_32_MAT', 'Leg_MAT'])

of this form (transform,[existing shader,expected_shader]) if expected shader already exists then assign it to and it not then create a new shader having same properties as existing_shader and then assign it to the transform ?

Comment: If I tested your script correctly, then you rename the shader which is assinged to any of the LT or RT geos and assign it to both sides, e.g. you use the shader assigned to LT_Hand_Geo, rename it to Hand_MAT and assign it to both sides. So what you could simply do is get the shader from one of the objects, rename it and assign it to both. No need for a dictionary at all. The result will be the same. The duplication was only for security in case the same shader is applied to other geos for some reason.

Comment: Yes but it is failing if the same shader is assigned to whole body in that case if we rename the shader it'll change the name for all the meshes , which won't be following correct convention then.

Comment: And exact for this reason you can duplicate the shader, rename it and assign it.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am trying to duplicate it and then assign it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411452/error-runtimeerror-file-maya-console-line-54-connection-not-made-lt-arm